# How to rename folder with God Mode String added?

Tags: windows-7, godmode

I tried the Windows Vista/7 God Mode thing in my XP system, it doesn't work, It simply blocks direct access to the folder :) But now i have Windows 7 installed and i cant find a way to rename it, Specifically this thing .{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}> after the folder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new folder
2. Name it foo.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
3. It should become the God Mode folder

(Note no "<" at the end of the string as in your question)

Edit:

To rename a God mode folder named "foo" back to a normal folder,

1. Open a command window. (Start, "cmd")
2. Navigate to where your folder is
3. Type "rename foo", press tab. (Should autocomplete; saves you a lot of typing)
4. Type the new folder name
5. Hit enter

> C:\Users\username\Desktop>dir
>
> Directory of C:\Users\username\Desktop
>
> 20/10/2010  19:22              foo.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
>                 0 File(s)              0 bytes
>                 1 Dir(s)  15,484,071,936 bytes free
>
> C:\Users\username\Desktop>rename "foo.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}" foo

Comment: Oh.. you got it wrong. Actually that folder is a God Mode folder,so i am having difficulty accessing its contents. How do i rename it to normal folder

Comment: Ah. I updated my answer.

Comment: It says "Access is denied"

Comment: @ketan - Try an elevated command prompt. (Type 'command prompt' into the Start Menu search, right-click, Run As Administrator, accept the UAC prompt, then proceed as before.)